# Generic tree implementation in Java

Tags: java, collections, reference, tree, generics

Is anyone aware of a generic tree (nodes may have multiple children) implementation for Java? It should come from a well trusted source and must be fully tested.

*It just doesn't seem right implementing it myself. Almost reminds me of my university years when we were supposed to write all our collections ourselves.*

EDIT: Found [this project](https://jsfcompounds.dev.java.net/treeutils/site/apidocs/com/truchsess/util/package-summary.html) on java.net, might be worth looking into.

Comment: How do you want to use this tree?

Comment: i.e. are you defining the structure yourself (like a family tree) or are the elements comparable and you want to insert them efficiently into the tree?

Comment: Every node should be able to keep a list of children in order of insertion. I need to do something like *postorder* traversal (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), traversing children of a node in reverse direction.

Comment: For tree traversal, you can take a look at Guava [TreeTraverser](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeTraverser.html)

Answer (score 25):

Here it comes:

```
abstract class TreeNode implements Iterable<TreeNode> {

  private Set<TreeNode> children;

  public TreeNode() {
    children = new HashSet<TreeNode>();
  }

  public boolean addChild(TreeNode n) {
    return children.add(n);
  }

  public boolean removeChild(TreeNode n) {
    return children.remove(n);
  }

  public Iterator<TreeNode> iterator() {
    return children.iterator();
  }
}
```

I am well trusted, but haven't tested the implementation.

Comment: Just make sure that TreeNode implements equals and hashCode properly.

Comment: Thanks, but I need something well tested, otherwise I'd have to spend a couple of hours writing unit tests from it myself...

Comment: How do you access the TreeNode's children exactly ? :P

Comment: @Ivan Seems like you would have to write unit tests anyways to test that your assumptions about the "well tested" code you are looking for are correct

Comment: @Martin, that's what makes it so secure!

Comment: @Martin There will be client tests for sure, but I don't want to write tests for the collection (Like, making sure it does null checks...)

Comment: equals and hashCode are optional and are based on how you define equality. You should not override them unless you need to.

Comment: +1 just for `I am well trusted, but haven't tested the implementation.` :)

Comment: missing the **generic** part

Answer (score 10):

There isn't a Tree class in the Collections libraries. However, there *is* one in the Swing Frameworks. [DefaultTreeModel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html)

I have used this in the past and it works well. It does pull in additional classes into your application though which may or may not be desirable.

You can also simulate a Tree using another collection and storing collections in it. Eg. List of Lists.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll give it a try. Interfaces at least look quite usable: javax.swing.tree.TreeNode.

Comment: I cannot understand why this isn't in the default collections API.

Comment: My guess is that it's not in the collection API because it does not add any extra to the collection implementations already available.

Answer (score 10):

## Use Guava

[Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [15.0](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Release15) introduces a nice API for tree traversal so you don't need to re-implement it for the gazillionth time in your codebase.

Namely, [`TreeTraverser`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeTraverser.html) and some specialized implementations, like [`BinaryTreeTraverser`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BinaryTreeTraverser.html).

A very much welcome [addition](https://plus.google.com/118010414872916542489/posts/SC3rhrQtXQG) to avoid re-implementing something so simple and with added bonus:

- with peace of mind (stability, supported library, etc...),
- good design,
- several traversal modes built-in.

## While You're There...

Notice that Guava also provides now new methods to its `Files` utility class that make use of the `TreeTraverser`, e.g. [`Files.fileTreeTraverser()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#fileTreeTraverser()) which gives you a `TreeTraverser<File>` for your file-system traversal needs.

Comment: But it's an abstract class, not a full implementation.

Comment: @quant_dev: yes, but it gets you 95% of the way to write your concrete typesafe class, rather than using a generic class that may not be a good fit for you. There are several ways to go about this, that's for sure. I was just surprised nobody had mentioned that one. If you want a concrete implementation, then the Swing DefaultTreeModel is actually pretty useful for this.

Comment: TreeTraverser is going to be removed in January 2019, use Traverser instead - https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html

Answer (score 8):

It's rather hard to do a true generic tree implementation in Java that really separated the tree operations and properties from the underlying implementations, i.e. swap in a RedBlackTreeNode and override a couple of method to get a RedBlackTree implementation while retaining all the generic operations that a BinaryTree interface contains.

Also, an ideal abstraction would be able to swap out the low-level tree representation, e.g. an implicit binary tree structure stored in an array for a Heap or a Node-base interface with left and right child pointers, or multiple child pointers, or augmenting any of the above with parent pointers, or threading the leaf nodes, etc, etc, etc.

I did try and solve this myself, but ended up with quite a complicated interface that still enforces type safety.  Here's the skeleton of the idea that sets up a abstract BinaryTree class with a non-trivial operation (Euler Tour) that will work even if the underlying node class or tree class is changed. It could probable be improved by introducing the idea of cursors for navigation and positions within the tree structure:

```
public interface Tree<E, P extends Tree.Entry<E, P>> extends Collection<E>
{
   public P getRoot();
   public Collection<P> children(P v);
   public E getValue(P v);

   public static interface Entry<T, Q extends Entry<T, Q>> { }
}

public interface BinaryTree<E, P extends BinaryTree.Entry<E, P>> extends Tree<E, P>
{
   public P leftChild(P v);
   public P rightChild(P v);

   public static interface Entry<T, Q extends Entry<T, Q>> extends Tree.Entry<T, Q>
   {
      public Q getLeft();
      public Q getRight();
   }
}

public interface TreeTraversalVisitor<E, P extends BinaryTree.Entry<E, P>, R> 
{
   public R visitLeft( BinaryTree<E, P> tree, P v, R result );
   public R visitCenter( BinaryTree<E, P> tree, P v, R result );
   public R visitRight( BinaryTree<E, P> tree, P v, R result );
}

public abstract class AbstractBinaryTree<E, P extends BinaryTree.Entry<E, P>> extends AbstractCollection<E> implements BinaryTree<E, P>
{
   public Collection<P> children( P v )
   {
      Collection<P> c = new ArrayList<P>( 2 );

      if ( hasLeft( v ))
         c.add( v.getLeft());

      if ( hasRight( v ))
         c.add( v.getRight());

      return c;
   }

   /**
    * Performs an Euler Tour of the binary tree
    */
   public static <R, E, P extends BinaryTree.Entry<E, P>> 
   R eulerTour( BinaryTree<E, P> tree, P v, TreeTraversalVisitor<E, P, R> visitor, R result )
   {
      if ( v == null )
         return result;

      result = visitor.visitLeft( tree, v, result );

      if ( tree.hasLeft( v ))
         result = eulerTour( tree, tree.leftChild( v ), visitor, result );

      result = visitor.visitCenter( tree, v, result );

      if ( tree.hasRight( v ))
         result = eulerTour( tree, tree.rightChild( v ), visitor, result );

      result = visitor.visitRight( tree, v, result );

      return result;
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Ah, I was going to post a shameless plug to my solution and saw that someone already posted a link to it. Yeah, I had the same issue and I basically ended up writing my own Generic Tree. I've got tests for the tree node and the tree itself.

I implemented the node as an object having a data field and a list of nodes (which are the children of that node).

http://vivin.net/2010/01/30/generic-n-ary-tree-in-java/

Answer (score 5):

I found an implementation of a Generic Tree (with tests) here:

http://vivin.net/2010/01/30/generic-n-ary-tree-in-java/

I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I found an absolutely fantastic library http://jung.sourceforge.net, see the javadoc http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/index.html . It is much more than just a graph implementation. With it you can visualize and layout graphs; plus, it has a bunch of standard graph algorithms you can use out of the box. 
*Go, check it out!* Although I ended up implementing my own basic graph (I didn't know of JUNG before), I use this library for visualization. It looks very neat!

Answer (score 0):

I use an XML DOM (XML describes a tree structure) and specifically the Open Source XOM (http://www.xom.nu). This is lightweight, nodes can be subclassed if required and very highly used and tested. It may be larger than you require but it has the advantage that any tree navigation methods (ancestors, siblings, etc.) are fully managed through XPath. You can also serialize the tree and transform it by tested XML methods. There is also a strong user community

Comment: XML is nice and all, but how can you use the word 'lightweight' with it?

Answer (score 0):

When in need of a tree I typically use following interface, and implement it accordingly.

```
  /**
   * Generic node interface
   * 
   * @param <T> type of contained data
   * @param <N> self-referential type boundary that captures the implementing type
   */
  interface Node<T, N extends Node<T, N>>
  {

    public T getObject();

    public boolean addChild(N node);

    public List<N> getChildren();

  }
```

An implementation could be

```
  class StringNode implements Node<String, StringNode>
  {

    private final String value;

    public StringNode(String value)
    {
      this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getObject()
    {
      return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addChild(StringNode node)
    {
      // add child
      return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<StringNode> getChildren()
    {
      // return children
      return Collections.emptyList();
    }

  }
```

The advantage here is the flexibility gained by implementing algorithms against the interface. A rather simple example could be

```
  public <T, N extends Node<T, ? extends N>> N performAlgorithm(N node)
  {
    if (!node.getChildren().isEmpty())
      return node.getChildren().get(0);

    return node;
  }
```

The method can be used with the inteface type or concrete implementations

```
StringNode sn = new StringNode("0");
Node<String, StringNode> node = sn;

// perform computations on the interface type
Node<String, StringNode> result = performAlgorithm(node);

// or use a concrete implementation
StringNode result2 = performAlgorithm(sn);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need an enterprise-level node tree, you could look into Java Content Repository ([JCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_repository_API_for_Java)). But it is far from the simple in-memory node tree solutions suggested here and more of a multi-user XML database with SQL and XPath.