# Is there an STL-Multiset equivalent container in Java?

Tags: java, collections, multimap

I'm still seeking an ideal solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254537/is-there-a-directed-acyclic-graph-dag-data-type-in-java-and-should-i-use-it). To summarize, I am modeling a power subsystem in Java and I need a Directed-Acyclic-Graph (DAG)-type container for my data.

I found exactly what I need in C++'s Standard Template Library (STL). It is the [multiset](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/multiset.html), which supports storing multiple data values for the same key. I can clearly see how storing power nodes and keys, and their upstream/downstream connections as values, could be pulled off with this data structure.

My customer has a hard-requirement that I write the power subsystem model in Java, so I need a data structure identical to the STL multiset. I could potentially roll my own, but it's late in the game and I can't afford the risk of making a mistake.

I'm supremely disappointed that Java is so light on Tree / Graph collections.

Has anyone found an multiset-type structure in Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HashMap with multiple values under the same key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956844/hashmap-with-multiple-values-under-the-same-key)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [Guava's Multiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html). In particular the [HashMultiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultiset.html) and the [TreeMultiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html).

Comment: [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) is what I'm really looking for. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Google's version: http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html

Comment: Google Collections is [deprecated](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/).  Use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) instead.