# jGraphT for Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, graph, jgrapht

I'm looking for a Directed Acyclic Graph implementation in Objective C. 
I've had enormous success with [jGraphT](http://www.jgrapht.org/javadoc/) in the Java space. I'm using a DirectedGraph to [model a power subsystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254537/is-there-a-directed-acyclic-graph-dag-data-type-in-java-and-should-i-use-it), and now I need equivalent code for iPhone/iPad.

Does such a thing exist in an open source library? Or do I need to roll my own?

Comment: You could try Objective-C++ & Boost for graph algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

There's no available implementation in Objective C at present. However, this should be very helpful, particularly Mark Wukta's PASCAL implementation.

See

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284928/directed-graph-implementation-in-objective-c/13310549#13310549

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is not Objective-C library for that. I needed a digraph and I [forked](https://github.com/j4n0/graph) Aaron Qian's [digraph](https://github.com/aq1018/digraph). Maybe add Tarjan's algorithm and you are almost there, but jgrapht is miles away in features.