# How to implement graph data structure in java? Is there any existing library available?

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, enterprise-library

I would like to implement a graph data structure in java to maintain a graph of objects. How should I achieve this? Is there a readily available library which could help?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574/good-java-graph-algorithm-library?rq=1)

Comment: 2 popular implementation of graph need 2-d array and list..both are available in java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Is there a readily available library which could help?`

[DSL](http://cs.brown.edu/cgc/jdsl/) is the Data Structures Library in Java

[JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/) is a free Java graph library that provides mathematical graph-theory objects and algorithms.

[JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) is the Java Universal Network/Graph Framework

Answer (score 2):

[JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/)
[JGRAPH](http://jgrapht.org/)

And read this may help you [javax.swing.tree.TreeModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978487/why-java-collection-framework-doesnt-contain-tree-and-graph/4979522#4979522)